# How to read excels merged header cells in pandas properly

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

How to read excels merged header cells as shown below in Pandas such that Frequency header can show up like Frequency_1, Frequency_2, Frequency_3

[image]

I am currently reading it as

```
data = (pandas.read_excel(excelfilename, sheetname, header)).values
```

while data read is correct but I end-up with header as

> ['Frequency' nan nan]

Comment: Maybe fillna(method ='ffill') should work

Answer (score 0):

if you want setting the header to the `Frequency_1`, `Frequency_2`, `Frequency_3`,
you can setting the header by hand.

```
data = (pandas.read_excel(excelfilename, sheetname, header=[Frequency_1, Frequency_2, Frequency_3]))
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

if you want fill the header with new value， please used this way：

```
>>> values = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3}
>>> df.fillna(value=values)
    A   B   C   D
0   0.0 2.0 2.0 0
1   3.0 4.0 2.0 1
2   0.0 1.0 2.0 5
3   0.0 3.0 2.0 4
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html